# Oracle Function Returning Null?

Tags: oracle

This is starting to drive me crazy and I cannot find the reason why this ain't working!

The tables have triggers on them so cityID and postcodeID get populated automatically. The purpose of this function is to find a city with the same name and return its ID else add it to the table and return the new ID.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION resolveCity(cityNameIn IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER AS
    cityIDOut NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT cityID
    INTO cityIDOut
    FROM tblCities
    WHERE cityName = cityNameIn;

    IF cityIDOut IS NULL THEN
        -- Add this city to the list
        INSERT INTO tblCities (cityName)
        VALUES (cityNameIn)
        RETURNING cityID INTO cityIDOut;
    END IF;

    RETURN(cityIDOut);
END;
/
```

Comment: Are the triggers BEFORE insert or AFTER insert?

Comment: BEFORE, it populates the primary key from sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a SELECT fails in PL/SQL a NO_DATA_FOUND exception is raised. In this case there's no handler in the function so it's raised to an outer handler - and apparently there isn't one, so it gets dropped on the floor and lost.

I suggest that you rewrite your function as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION resolveCity(cityNameIn IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER AS
    cityIDOut NUMBER;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT cityID
      INTO cityIDOut
      FROM tblCities
      WHERE cityName = cityNameIn;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      -- Add this city to the list
      INSERT INTO tblCities (cityName)
        VALUES (cityNameIn)
        RETURNING cityID INTO cityIDOut;
  END;

  RETURN(cityIDOut);
END;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately this returns me: ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query ORA-06512: at "S.RESOLVECITY", line 13 ORA-01403: no data found

Comment: How are you invoking this function?

Comment: Could you use MERGE and return the new id?

Comment: INSERT INTO tblCustomerAddresses (userID, defaultAddress, addressLine1, addressLine2, addressLine3, cityID, postcodeID, countryCode)
 VALUES(userIDout, 1, sAddressLine1, sAddressLine2, sAddressLine3, resolveCity(sAddressCity), resolvePostcode(sAddressPostcode), sAddressCountry);

Comment: I will trying using the MERGE, just need to look it up - thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thank you, I made a critical error here, which was that I tried to modify a table through a SELECT statement which doesn't work. I have changed the function into a procedure and used your concept of NO_DATA_FOUND. Thanks!